# Null Quantification with empty domain

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is Null Quantification false?

Null Quantification state that
$\exists x [P \lor Q(x)]\equiv P\lor\exists x[Q(x)]$

;  $P$ represents any wff in which $x$ does not occur free.

If we set domain of discourse be empty and let T be tautology

we will get $\exists x [\text{T} \lor Q(x)]$ is false.
But $\text{T}\lor\exists x[Q(x)]$ is true.

Comment: We do not normally consider empty domains. There are many inference rules which also don't work for empty domains.

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

Not all *valid* sentences are *inclusive valid*, i.e. true in all interpretations,
including the interpretation with an empty domain.

Example: $(\forall x) \bot$ is true in the empty domain (because all universaly quantified formulas are) and thus  $(\forall x) \bot \to \bot$ is false.

But it is *valid*, because all instances of $(\forall x) \varphi \to \varphi$ are.

If so, it seems that you have proved that :

> $∃x[ \top \lor Q(x)] \leftrightarrow (\top \lor ∃x[Q(x)])$

is *valid* but not *inclusive valid*.

See e.g. E.Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic (6th ed, 2015)](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA146) **Ch.2.16 Quantification Theory Allowing Empty Domains**, page 146-on.